# details from where site has been opened?

Tags: php, geography, gis

I want to know that how the details of the viewers could be traced in php?. Actually I need to trace out  No. of hits into my website, from which geographical locations, Level of threats, Graphical Presentation of activities, Country and Language of the viewed customer, Status of the website showing the process and performance, which menu gets more hit from client side, IP’s of the viewed customer  etc. ??

Kindly show me some posible ways.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Geolocation by IP is a well covered topic. As for the rest, you mostly extract that from the request headers. Or use one of the myriad existing analytics packages.

Comment: Details of the viewer can be traced using ip. Get the ip of user and using that ip, distinguish regions. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775655/ip-address-to-country-with-database

Comment: You can get real ip using http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/getting-real-ip-address-in-php.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://piwik.org/ ... I believe that it has an [API](http://dev.piwik.org/trac/wiki/API) that will let you access the specific details you want if you don't want to use their reporting dashboard.

Another example package is http://www.openwebanalytics.com/

Personally I would not reinvent the wheel when there is an OSS solution and it doesn't sound like you're ready to create an alternative to these packages.